# captcha class wont display image if an instance is made outside of class file

Tags: php, oop, class, include, captcha

I made a captcha class to generate a captcha. for some reason I can only get the image to display if I make an instance of the class in the class file itself. otherwise I get nothing. In firebug I see the file being included but its being sent as html despite I used `header("Content-type: image/png");`
`class.captcha.php`

```
<?php
class captcha
{

    public $length=4;
    public $width=150;
    public $height=50;
    public $allowedChar='1234569ACEFGHJKMNPQRSTXZ';
    public $font='Arcade.ttf';
    public $fontSize=25;
    public $fontRed=0;
    public $fontGreen=0;
    public $fontBlue=104;
    public $backgroundRed=204;
    public $backgroundGreen=204;
    public $backgroundBlue=255;
    public $noiseRed=0;
    public $noiseGreen=0;
    public $noiseBlue=104;
    public $noisePercent=5;

    /*
    ** @RETURN IMAGE raw image of captcha
    */
    public function create($name)
    {
        //string
        for ($i=0;$i<$this->length;$i++) 
        {$captcha.= $this->allowedChar[mt_rand(0, strlen($this->allowedChar))];}

        //image
        $img=imagecreatetruecolor($this->width, $this->height);
        //colors
        $bgColor=imagecolorallocate($img, $this->backgroundRed, $this->backgroundGreen, $this->backgroundBlue);
        $fontColor=imagecolorallocate($img, $this->fontRed, $this->fontGreen, $this->fontBlue);
        $noiseColor=imagecolorallocate($img, $this->noiseRed, $this->noiseGreen, $this->noiseBlue);
        imagefilledrectangle($img,0,0,$this->width+1,$this->height+1,$bgColor);
        //text
        for($i=0;$i<strlen($captcha);$i++)
        {
            $rotate=rand(0, 80)-40;
            $offX=$i*$this->fontSize+rand($this->fontSize, $this->fontSize*1.2);
            $offY=$this->fontSize+rand($this->fontSize/2, $this->fontSize);;
            $letter=$captcha[$i];
            imagettftext($img, $this->fontSize, $rotate, $offX, $offY, $fontColor, $this->font, $letter);
        }
        //add noise
        for($i=0;$i<$this->height*$this->width*($this->noisePercent/100);$i++)
        {
            //noise
            $x=rand(0, $this->width);
            $y=rand(0, $this->height);
            imagesetpixel($img, $x, $y, $noiseColor);
        }
        $_SESSION[$name]=md5($captcha);
        return $img;
    }
}
?>
```

`captcha.contact.php`

```
<?php
session_start(); 
include('class.captcha.php');
$c=new captcha;
header("Content-type: image/png"); 
imagepng($c->create('contactCaptcha'));
?>
```

link to above if it helps http://yamikowebs.com/_test/_php/class.captcha.php
the error is `The image “http://yamikowebs.com/_test/_php/captcha.contact.php” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.`
if i put the contents of capture.contact.php at the end of class.captcha.php it works no problem.

Comment: Turn error reporting to show all the errors and notices and then tell us what you see: [`error_reporting()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`contact.captcha.php`

```
<?php
include('class.captcha.php');
$c=new captcha;
header("Content-type: image/png"); 
imagepng($c->create('contactCaptcha'));
?>
```

`session_start()` sends header information so once removed it started working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution may be the fact you are using the closing tags of PHP:

```
?>
```

They are not required, but sometimes harmful. If there is any sign after such tag, the headers that you are trying to send will not be sent and the notice may appear (depending on the error_reporting setting).

Just **remove closing tags (`?>`)** and this should be ok.

One additional thing - if something is required for the script to work (such as your class file), use `require()` instead of `include()`.

Comment: @yamikoWebs: Did you remove closing tags from both files?

Comment: also using require a you have suggested.

Comment: @yamikoWebs: If you are including file correctly (with correct path), use only these two script files (I doubt it), then you probably send something to the browser before you are trying to send another header. Thus I suggest you to remove the closing tags, turn on the error reporting (`error_reporting(-1)`, afair), prepare both cases (image from the class and from outside of it) and give us links, then we will probably solve your problem.

Comment: sorry I was refreshing class file not the file with instance. The image “http://yamikowebs.com/_test/_php/captcha.contact.php” cannot be displayed because it contains errors. is the error

Comment: @yamikoWebs: Remove all occurences of `?>` as I asked, add `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` at the beginning of `captcha.contact.php` and update the code accordingly, please.

Comment: i posted an answer. i cant vote it yet. as i said many times I removed the ?> with no difference. the problem was that I used session_start() which stopped the php from sending the image header.